# Automapper 10 wouldn't map collection properties when setting MaxDepth to 1

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-5, automapper-10

Properties of type ICollection are not mapped when migrating from Automapper 9 to 10. I am using .NET 5.

I have the following setup:

```
private class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

private class Class2
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Class1> ChildClasses { get; set; }
}

private class Class2Bis
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Class1> ChildClasses { get; set; }
}

private class MapperProfile : Profile
{
     public MapperProfile()
     {
          CreateMap<Class2, Class2Bis>().ReverseMap();
     }
}
```

I am injecting the mapper using a helper method that uses AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection module:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMapper(this IServiceCollection services, params Assembly[] assemblies)
{
    return services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.ForAllMaps((map, exp) => exp.MaxDepth(1));
        cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
        cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.GetMethod.IsPublic || p.GetMethod.IsAssembly;
    },
    assemblies);
}
```

The following test succeeds using Automapper 9 but fails using Automapper 10:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Should_Map_ClassesWithCollectionProperties()
    {
        var object2 = new Class2
        {
            Id = 1,
            ChildClasses = new List<Class1>() 
            {
                new Class1 
                {
                    Id = 1
                }
            }
        };

        var object2Bis = _mapper.Map<Class2Bis>(object2);

        Assert.Equal(object2.ChildClasses.Count, object2Bis.ChildClasses.Count);
    }
```

object2Bis has an empty ChildClasses property when using Automapper 10.

Comment: this looks like a detailed bug report, but there isn’t any question. Maybe you should create an issue at the Automapper github repository https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: @Stephan, auto mapper definitely supports this functionality. Its probably a configuration issue not a bug.

Comment: It seems that this can be a bug. Removing `cfg.ForAllMaps((map, exp) => exp.MaxDepth(1));` makes everything work. But `MaxDepth` is described as "For self-referential types, limit recurse depth" but I can't see (self)reference loops here.

Comment: @GuruStron I confirm that removing the MaxDepth configuration line makes it work properly. I use it as common configuration to prevent self referencing loops as sometimes in my projects when mapping EF entities to other models I have self refenrcing issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `cfg.ForAllMaps((map, exp) => exp.MaxDepth(1));` or setting `MaxDepth` to 2 (or higher number) makes the code work for me. There is next note in the [10.0 Upgrade Guide](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/10.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?#maxdepth):

> When reaching `MaxDepth`, destination collections are null/empty, they used to contain null values.

Comment: That's my answer. I think I should correct the title to be more precise

Comment: @Mouad was glad to help!